# Distribution of free space between collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to use collection view as week days picker.

[image]

Height and width of cell are constant. I'd like to position cells to fill full collection view width. I've tried this but doesn't work for me:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        let collectionWidth = collectionView.frame.width
        let freeSpace = collectionWidth - 210

        return freeSpace / 7
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let collectionWidth = (collectionView.frame.width - numberOfItems * 30 ) / (numberOfItems - 1)
     return collectionWidth
}
```

where `numberOfItems` = array datasource count of the collection

---

You may need

```
return freeSpace / 6
```

instead of

```
return freeSpace / 7
```

as you need to divide by `numOfelements - 1` which is the correct count of spaces between the 7 items